# Sinatra cookie for client application

Tags: javascript, ruby, cookies, client-server, sinatra

I have got a server for which I use sinatra and rack and a simple client application (Java/JavaScript, running on Tomcat) which should consume the services my server offers. 
My browser displays the client application and this application then sends requests to a server. Now I've got a question:

Is it possible to set cookies from the ruby server to the browser?

And if yes: How can I do this?

So far I do it like this

```
cookies[:user_id] = user_id
```

as described here in [the sinatra documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/cookies.html).

When I request my sinatra server directly with the browser it sets a cookie. But not when I request it via my application. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're setting cookies on the client side (Java app) because that's the endpoint requesting from your sinatra app. In order to set a cookie in the browser you'd have to forward these cookies or use them as third party cookies, poosibly by making a direct request to the sinatra app. I'd probably forward the cookies from the middle app to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how do I forward the cookie? Is there any special javascript method to access the cookie?.. I can see it in the console, but I don't know how to handle with it.